# phpDocumentor 2 web interface error "Strict standards: declaration of xxx should be compatible..."

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, phpdoc, phpdocumentor2

I'm attempting to use the phpDocumentor web interface to generate documentation for a CodeIgniter project. When I attempt to parse the directory, I get a long list of "Strict standards" errors that all look like this

"Strict standards: Declaration of parserTag::getString() should be compatible with parserStringWithInlineTags::getString($trim = true) in D:\wamp\www\phpdoc\phpDocumentor\DocBlockTags.inc on line 185"

"Strict standards: Declaration of phpDocumentorTParser::packageTagHandler() should be compatible with Parser::packageTagHandler($word) in D:\wamp\www\phpdoc\phpDocumentor\phpDocumentorTParser.inc on line 2945"

"Strict standards: Declaration of phpDocumentor_TutorialHighlightParser::setupStates() should be compatible with Parser::setupStates() in D:\wamp\www\phpdoc\phpDocumentor\TutorialHighlightParser.inc on line 527"

Can anyone tell me what would cause this, or whether it's related to the phpdoc installation or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

phpDocumentor 1.x is php4 code, and so running it on newer versions (especially 5.3+) triggers many such notices and warnings.  You can lower your error reporting threshold to hide them, but a better option for newer PHP code is to try phpDocumentor 2.x, which is in beta right now.

As for these notices having a negative effect on the docs you generate using 1.x, your docs should be fine.  Those particular notices are not failures of any kind.